# segmentation fault while trying to read in from file to a 2D array

Tags: c, segmentation-fault, dynamic-arrays

I am getting a segmentation fault while trying to read from a file into a 2D dynamic array. I know this is a little vague of a question, but this being my first C code, I haven't been able to trace out what the problem is. Any direction will be appreciated.
These are my variables:

```
int i;
    int rowsize=0;
    int colsize=0;
    int colenter=0;
    int rowenter=0;
    int colexit=0;
    int rowexit=0;

    char  sizestring[20];
    char  enterstring[20];
    char  exitstring[20];
    int   line=0;
    int j;
    int k;
    char**mazearray;
    FILE*file;
```

And this is my allocation.

```
mazearray = (char**) malloc(sizeof(char*)*rowsize);

    for(i =0; i<rowsize; ++i)
    {
            mazearray[i]= (char*)malloc(sizeof(char)*colsize);
    }
```

And this is me trying to read from a file and parse the information. I first try to read in 3 lines of strings which contain the information about a maze (Array size, enterance, exit etc.) and then try to fill out the 2d array with the for loop at the bottom.

```
file = fopen(argv[1],"r");

    if (!file)
    {
            printf("The file is not connected/n");
    }
    while (!feof(file))
    {

            while(line<3)
            {
                    if(line==0)
                    {

                            fgets(sizestring,20,file);
                            sscanf(sizestring,"%d,%d", &colsize, &rowsize);
                            line++;
                    }
                    else if(line ==1)
                    {
                            fgets(enterstring,20,file);
                            sscanf(enterstring,"%d,%d",&colenter, &rowenter);
                            line++;
                    }
                    else if(line ==2)
                    {
                            fgets(exitstring,20,file);
                            sscanf(exitstring, "%d,%d", &colexit, &rowexit);
                            line++;
                    }
            }
            for(j=0; j<rowsize; j++)
            {
                    for(k=0; k<colsize; k++)
                    {
                            fscanf(file,"%c",&mazearray[j][k]);
                    }
            }
    }
    fclose(file);
```

Again any direction will help. Thanks

Comment: So when are you doing the allocations? Before reading the actual size?

Comment: i think the problem may be here `int rowsize=0; int colsize=0;`

Comment: Can you add error log and sample data in your file?

Comment: The allocation should be after reading line 0 from the file

Comment: Pointer to a pointer allocation =\= 2D array

Comment: Also see https://stackoverflow.com/q/5431941/4386427

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`rowSize` and `colSize` are both zero:

```
mazearray = (char**) malloc(sizeof(char*)*rowsize);

for(i =0; i<rowsize; ++i)
{
        mazearray[i]= (char*)malloc(sizeof(char)*colsize);
}
```

No bytes will be allocated to `mazearray`. The `for` loop will be executed no times.

I see you read in `rowSize` and `colSize` from `stdin` but having read them, you do not allocate your arrays at any point with the new sizes.

Comment: Thank you. I am not having seg fault anymore. But I still can't read in with the for loop at the bottom. I can read the first three lines.